# Apache Remote Logging

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, log-files

I am investigating the possibility of logging Apache access & error_logs into one central repository, as opposed to each server having their own log files.

Does anyone have any ideas or best practises on how to do this? Anyone can push me in the right direction?

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rsyslog, see http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Working_Apache_and_Rsyslog_configuration

To log everything to a remote server put in /etc/rsyslog.d/0X-remote-server.conf:

```
*.* @<IP-address remote server>
```

Then on the remote server you can use for instance syslog-ng with filters to put
all logging in seperate directories (i.e. per VirtualHost).

If you log over the network it's wise to encrypt your data. You can use stunnel for this
(http://www.stunnel.org/).

Comment: Thanks Oscar, that looks like a very good solution. I will investigate  further. Steve.